# php undefined variables error when displaying pdf with mpdf

Tags: include, mpdf

i have been in crisis for over 2 days with this pdf thing.Its not showing any error in the resulting action page,still not displaying in pdf document.Can anyone plz sort this this out, maybe a simple one i guess not sure.The code is below.
Anyways thanks in advance,all.

```
    <?php
      if(isset($_POST['email'])){
       $email = $_POST['email'];
       $fileno = $_POST['fileno'];
       $header = $_POST['header'];
       $day = $_POST['day'];
       $month = $_POST['month'];
       $year = $_POST['year'];
       $stime = $_POST['stime'];
       $venue = $_POST['venue'];
       $meettype = $_POST['meettype'];
       $Itchair = $_POST['Itchair'];
       $mem_pres = $_POST['mem_pres'];
       $invite = $_POST['invite'];

       $head = $_POST['head'];
       $slno = $_POST['slno'];
       $subject = $_POST['subject'];
       $decision = $_POST['decision'];
       $incharge = $_POST['incharge'];
       $date = $_POST['date'];
       $remarks = $_POST['remarks']; 
  }




        include("MPDF54/mpdf.php");

        $mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','' , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0);

        $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

        $mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;  

        $mpdf->WriteHTML(file_get_contents("http://localhost/Bescom/besc_latest.php?email=$email&fileno=$fileno&header=$header&day=$day&month=$month&year=$year&stime=$stime&venue=$venue&meettype=$meettype&Itchair=$Itchair&mem_pres=$mem_pres&invite=$invite&head=$head&slno=$slno&subject=$subject&decision=$decision&date=$date&incharge=$incharge&remarks=$remarks"));

        $mpdf->Output();


     ?>
```

Comment: the pdf is reading only the html part of php file, for the php part the values passed with the form not read, displays 'undefined variable' in pdf document..

Answer (score 0):

Add following at top of mpdf.php

```
error_reporting(0);
```

This will resolved the issue.

Comment: No,it has just blocked the errors and it is displaying nothing but blank page..No pdf document generated.